# Allowing users in from an IP address without certificate client authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, certificate

I need to allow access to my site without SSL certificates from my office network and with SSL certificates outside.

Here is my configuration:

```
 <Directory /srv/www>
  AllowOverride All

  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  # office network static IP
  Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

  SSLVerifyClient require
  SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth
  AuthName "My secure area"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/ssl/index
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy Any

 </Directory>
```

When I'm inside network and have certificate - I can access.
When I'm inside network and haven't certificate - I can't access, it requires certificate.

When I'm outside network and have certificate  - I can't access, it shows me basic login screen
When I'm outside network and haven't certificate  - I can't access, it shows me basic login screen

and following configuration works perfectly

```
 <Directory /srv/www>
  AllowOverride All

  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

  AuthUserFile /srv/www/htpasswd
  AuthName "Restricted Access"
  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy Any

 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how I implemented that(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - allow access for this address without cert) :

```
  SSLVerifyClient optional
  SSLOptions -FakeBasicAuth +StrictRequire -StdEnvVars -ExportCertData
  SSLRequire %{SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE} >= 128

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} !^SUCCESS$
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx$
  RewriteRule   ^  -  [F]
```

Note that SSLVerifyClient should NOT be in directory context:

> In per-directory context it forces a SSL renegotiation with the
>   reconfigured client verification level after the HTTP request was read
>   but before the HTTP response is sent.

Comment: Thank you very much for having come back to provide the answer. Could you accept your own answer please?

Comment: Ok, I thought that I should not accept my answer because it may be treated as rank cheating

Comment: I'm not sure if you earn points when you accept your own answer. However marking a question as answered is important as it does not appear in the unanswered anymore.

Comment: This is a very underrated answer!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, inside your network, the server has a different (internal, private) IP than when accessed from the outside.

In that case, it would be simplest to set up two vhosts - one on in.ter.nal.ip:443, and one on ex.ter.nal.ip:443.

Require client certificates only on the external vhost.

Comment: server is not in my office network

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to find this works in Apache 2.4:

```
<LocationMatch "^/some/secure/place">
    <If "! -R 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32'">
            SSLRequireSSL
            SSLVerifyClient require
            ...etc
    </If>
</LocationMatch>
```