# apache client cert conditionally

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, https, reverse-proxy

seems to me very strange I couldn't find information neither questions but I'm in the situation of serving some sites over an apache reverse proxy.

I have to switch all the traffic (also lan) over https on the apache. it actually uses both a server and client cert to connect to those sites over https.

I need a workaround for the client cert, totally unneeded from the intranet ip ranges while mandatory for the rest of the world.

The apache use virtual hosts with a

```
<location / >

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
  .... otherstuff ......

</location>
```

for the client cert as I have no SNI capable apache so the server wildcard cert is on the first virtual-host while the client certs are re-negotiated in the location part. An option is upgrade apache to a SNI capable version, but seems to me not useful for my porpoises.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer to [Allowing users in from an IP address without certificate client authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/411858/allowing-users-in-from-an-ip-address-without-certificate-client-authentication). Basically, you use mod_rewrite to check whether the client has been verified and if so, let them through. If not, fall-back to an IP check.

Note that you should put your `SSLVerifyClient` statement at the root level of your configuration to avoid costly SSL renegotations.

Comment: This solution could serves the porpoise, but as I have no nsi capable server, I can't use these rules on root (I have multiple site and at least 3 different certs). 
An interesting thought was the answer about the internal / external ip: as the apache proxy is natted, I could use multiple virtual interfaces to supply the lack of sni. Do you think is an opportunity?

Comment: I tried the solution talked on the post, and i have to say it satisfied me at 80%. everything is working as expected but everytime, for every user, the apache is going to ask a certificate if i had any installed. That is very annoying and suggest me that could be a different solution to check the ip previously than asking the client cert.